# How do I parse the second IP address in the following payload using regex?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, xml-parsing

Payload:

```
2016-07-18 16:51:47 GMT 10.65.242.97        WinNT://CSLG1\mbr04105  CONNECT https   stats.g.doubleclick.net 443 /           -   1925    5148    0       173.194.206.156 c:infr  default allow           12.3.33.9
```

Current Regex to parse an IP (it grabs the first IP right now)

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Comment: Post your code please. You can simply call ``find`` again using a matcher.

Comment: You should replace `if` with `while`, right? See http://ideone.com/HSTQ3T.

Comment: I mean you can collect all the matches, and then access any you wish.

Answer (score -1):

In order to grab the first and second addresses in one expression, anchor to the text line start and place two IP address pattern delimited by non-greedy fillers:

```
^.*?((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*?((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/FlREEd

Answer (score -1):

**Use the Class Patter AND Matcher.**

**Code :**

```
String yourString = ...
Pattern regular = Pattern.compile("your regex");
Matcher match = regular.matcher(yourString);
match.find()//to make the match
String firstIP = yourString.substring(match.start(),match.end());
String newString = yourString.substring(match.end(),yourString.length());
regular = Pattern.compile("your new regex for the second IP");
//if it is the same regex you can skip this.
match = regular.matcher(newString);
match.find()
String secondIP = newString.substring(match.start(),match.end());
```